# Linear regression in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

How could I make a linear regression with several value equals on `x` with MATLAB?

Now, an example with minimal data (not the data I use) :

```
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
x = [2,2,2,4,4,6,6,6,10,10];
```

If I use `polyfit` or `\`:

```
x = temp(:,1); y = temp(:,2);
b1 = x\y;
yCalc1 = b1*x;
plot(x,yCalc1,'-r');
```

Then the linear regression is wrong because (I suppose) he didn't notice that several values have got the same (`x`).

Here, a graph with my real data. Blue dots: my data. Red line : the linear regression (it's wrong). Don't focus to green dash line:

[image]

And here, the "same" graph (done with Excel):
Blue dots: my data. Red line : the linear regression (it's right)

[image]

Du you think that if I do a `mean` for each yvalues with the same `x`, it's mathematicaly right ?

Comment: Did you try fit a linear model? http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html?refresh=true

Comment: I edited my message with a suggestion. But I don't know if it's a good idea...
I don't try your function. I'm going to read it.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) since it seems as if you need to learn how to write a linear regression model with multiple (and presumable different amount of values) for each point.

Comment: Well, I find exactly the same linear regression with the function give by Dan on `matlab` and `excel`.

Thank's guys ! :)

Comment: `b1 = x\y` is not linear regression. You can do [linear regression with simple linear algebra](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Linear_regression#/Least-squares_estimation_and_related_techniques), but not *that* simple!

Comment: Well, `b1 = x\y` isn't a linear regression but a possible step to make a linear regression.

Fitting my datas with a linear model work ;) Thank's a lot :)

Comment: `b1 = x\y` is simple linear regression assuming the model is y = bx. If you are looking for y = b1*x + b0, you need to modify you matrix. See my answer.

Comment: The `\` operator can indeed perform linear regression (http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html). I'm curious as to what other forms it would take?

Answer (score 3):

If you intended to solve simple linear regression with matrix form Y= XB and the operator `\`, you need to add an additional column of ones in your X for calculating the intercepts.

```
y0 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
x0 = [2,2,2,4,4,6,6,6,10,10];
X1 = [ones(length(x0),1)  x0'];
b = X1\y0';
y = b(1) + x0*b(2)
plot(x0,y0,'o')
hold on
plot(x0,y,'--r')
```

You can find a good Matlab example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html)

Answer (score 0):

So, Dan suggests me a `function` and it's working now.

If you want to do the same thing, just do like that :
use the `fitlm` function (http://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html?refresh=true#bunfd6c-2)

Example datas :

```
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
x = [2,2,2,4,4,6,6,6,10,10];

tbl = table(x,y)
lm = fitlm(tbl,'linear')
```

and you will have different values.

A linear regression is an equation as `y = ax + b`. Here, on result, `a` correspond to `x` (bellow equal to `0.15663`) and `b` correspond to `(Intercept)` (bellow equal to `1.4377`).

With other values, Matlab will show you this result :

```
Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x

Estimated Coefficients:
                   Estimate       SE        tStat       pValue   
                   ________    _________    ______    ___________

    (Intercept)     1.4377      0.031151    46.151    5.8802e-290
    x              0.15663     0.0054355    28.816    1.2346e-145
Number of observations: 1499, Error degrees of freedom: 1497
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.135
R-squared: 0.357,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.356
F-statistic vs. constant model: 830, p-value = 1.23e-145
```

Thank's to Dan again !